# Owl Carousel stops rotating after following link

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I have an Owl Carousel slider setup to display sponsor logos for a site. It currently has links to external pages for each image within the slider. When clicking on a link (which opens in a new tab) the slider stops rotating. Is there a way for the slider to continue rotating once the user has followed a link and then returns to the tab?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="partners">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <p> <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300" /></a>
        </p>
        <h5>
        Platinum Sponsor
        </h5>
    </div>
... 
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#partners').owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        autoPlay: true,
        loop: true,
        stopOnHover : false
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/x1x10nz1/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much a technical answer but more as a suggestion/answer:

I don't think it's a good UI not to stop a slider on hover.
*A user wants to click on an item but hey! Bam! we slided! yey!*.
So simply use: `stopOnHover : true`  and it will work all out of the box.
Click, get back and see your slider... autoslide again.